# Each Thread using unique ID and releasing it for reuse

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Below is the code in which in the `run method`, I am always trying to get `unique id from the availableExistingIds` and `releasing` it at the same moment by making a `linked list order`, but in certain cases I found out that, I am getting `NoSuchElementException` and id is `zero few times` which I think should not be the case anytime.

```
class IdPool {
    private final LinkedList<Integer> availableExistingIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public IdPool() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            availableExistingIds.add(i);
        }
    }

    public synchronized Integer getExistingId() {
        return availableExistingIds.removeFirst();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseExistingId(Integer id) {
        availableExistingIds.add(id);
    }
}


class ThreadNewTask implements Runnable {
    private IdPool idPool;
    private int id;

    public ThreadNewTask(IdPool idPool) {
        this.idPool = idPool;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            id = idPool.getExistingId();
            //Anything wrong here?  
                    if(id==0) {
                        System.out.println("Found Zero");
                    }
            someMethod(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            idPool.releaseExistingId(id);
        }
    }

    // This method needs to be synchronized or not?
            private synchronized void someMethod(Integer id) {
                System.out.println("Task: " +id);
                // and do other calcuations whatever you need to do in your program
            }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

How can I avoid this `zero id case` here in my code? One scenario under which I can get id = 0 is when the id pool is exhausted (empty). When that happens, the line:

```
id = idPool.getExistingId();
```

will fail with a `NoSuchElementException`. In this case, the finally block will run:

```
idPool.releaseExistingId(id);
```

But id will still have its `default value of 0` since the first line failed. So I end up "releasing" `0` and adding it back to the id pool even though it was never in the pool to start with. Then a later task could take 0 legitimately. And that's what I don't need. Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this scenario in my code? I always want id should be in the range of `1 to 1000`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why don't you modify your code so that instead of crashing when there are no available ids, it waits for one to become available?

Otherwise, every time you have too much threads working at once, the pool is going to be exhausted, and you are going to have to deal with a lot of failing threads. Also the synchronization work is taken care of for you automatically.

EDIT: here is the modified code

```
class ThreadNewTask implements Runnable {
  private BlockingQueue<Integer> pool;
  private int id;

  public ThreadNewTask(BlockingQueue<Integer> pool) {
    this.pool = pool;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
        id = pool.take();
        someMethod(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        pool.offer(id);
    }
  }

  private void someMethod(Integer id) {
    System.out.println("Task: " +id);
            // and do other calcuations whatever you need to do in your program
  }
}
```

And then you initialize the pool with something like this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> availableExistingIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  availableExistingIds.add(i);
}
BlockingQueue<Integer> pool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1000, false, availableExistingIds);
```

Comment: Thanks Mario for the suggestion. That makes sense to me. Can you edit my code basis on your suggestion. It will be of great help as I just started learning multithreading and ArrayBlcokingQueue concept is new to me. So by that way I can understand how to use all these things in one shot. Thanks.

Comment: And in my case `availableExistingIds` is not an integer, it's an `LinkedList`

Comment: Thanks Mario for the edit, When I tried the same thing, I was getting something like this- `The constructor ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(LinkedList<Integer>) is undefined` And it is suggesting me to change the type of `availableExistingIds to int`. Why is it so?

Comment: you are right, the constructor is actually `public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair, Collection<? extends E> c)`

Comment: Yup..Thanks for making me clear. So capacity of  `ArrayBlockingQueue` should always be same as the size of `availableExistingIds`, so in our case capacity should always be same as the size of `availableExistingIds` i.e. `1000`?

Comment: yes, if you try to add further elements when the queue is full you'll get an exception. If you can predict the size, or need more flexibility, you can use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead